# remove_const inside template class for type

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am working on the test implementation of simple containers that should be able to accept consts values. My goal is to understand how templates do this and provide a clear external interface.

So my task creates a container that accepts const values. ( Below just one method stripped down to a minimum code)

```
 const std::string const_string1 = std::string("test");
 MyVector<const std::string> myVector;
 myVector.push_back(const_string1);
```

The solution I came up.

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector {

public:

    MyVector();

    void push_back(const T &value);
    T &operator[](unsigned int index);

private:
    typename std::remove_const<T>::type *ptr;
    int elemSize;
};

// I removed everthing only most important i.e remove_const
template<typename T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(const T &value) {

    if (ptr == nullptr) {
        ptr = new typename std::remove_const<T>::type[4];
    }
    ptr[elemSize] = value;
    elemSize++;
}
```

Notice the use of remove_const.

Do you see is it valid use?  Can I express this differently?  Is there any other recommended method to do this and how Vector STL does it for a same case I've described? (I know that before 2011 standard you couldn't pass a const string to Vector)

if I don't remove const from the original type it will fail during compilation
i.e it will not work if I don't strip const from the original type and ill not be able to copy the value.

```
    ptr[elemSize] = value;
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Only thing I can really see is I'd probably have a `using value_type = typename std::remove_const<T>::type` inside the class definition to avoid having to type it over and over again.

Comment: @Ayjay could you please explain how I can do that?

Comment: Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/aZzXedsW)

Comment: Ah cool, thank you very much !.  I didn't know that I can use value_type like that :)